# Divs connect to each other

Tags: html, css

I'm currently having trouble with my css layout: 
http://jsfiddle.net/XB2r7/1/

```
.content {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color:rgba(64,64,64,0.9);
width: 1000px;
height: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border: 1px solid #333;
color: #fff;
overflow: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #333;
}
.sidebar {
width: 23.5%;
height: auto;
display: block;
float: left;
color: #000;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
.content2 {
width: 73.5%;
height: auto;
display: block;
float: right;
color: #000;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
.h1 {
font-weight: bold;
}
.content hr {
border: 0;
height: 2px;
background: url('bg3.jpg');
}
```

As you can see at JSFiddle the two sidebars are connecting to each other, obviously I don't want this to happen, how can I fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by connecting? that there are no space between?

Comment: margin-bottom on sidebar perhaps? you have it on content so I assume you know what it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add some `margin-bottom;` to the sidebars to "disonnect" them from each other.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/XB2r7/2/)**

(added `margin-bottom : 10px;` to `.sidebar`)

Or if you just want to separate the last `.sidebar` you can add

```
.sidebar:last-child {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/XB2r7/3/)**